# What should I grab as a development platform, an iPod or an iPad?

Tags: ipad, ipod-touch

I've recently gotten into the world of contract programming, and two of my clients have indicated that they'd like to do something 'trendy', like ipod touch/iphone/ipad development.  I have a mac laptop (first gen macbook pro) that I'll have to upgrade to snow leopard to do the development for any of them, from what [I've read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990522/iphone-development-leopard-or-snow-leopard).  So that's already a bit of a commitment, given all the stuff I have on that laptop I'll have to make sure is recoverable from backup.

My budget is limited, but I think I need to learn this skill.  Which device should I get to learn this kind of development, an iPod touch or an iPad?  I don't have the money for an iPhone.

I think that the iPhone/iPad SDK has an emulator mode, but I like to have the device I'm going to roll out on available to make sure that everything works as I'd expect, ie, what's easily readable on a laptop screen is still readable on the touch, etc.

Comment: Another question:  you say "first gen macbook pro".  Is that a PPC Mac or an Intel?  You'll need an Intel Mac for development.  Fortunately, you can get a Mac Mini for roughly the price of an iPad.

Comment: Intel.  I thought that the macbook pros were all intel?  Shows how into the whole mac development scene I am.

Comment: Either way, if you are on a limited budget, for learning you can watch the Stanford cs193p classes on ITunes U.  They are a great resource for getting started and are completely free!.

Comment: @Jon-- I would have definitely upvoted that answer, thanks!

Comment: Clients that want something trendy: that's a warning signal.

Comment: @Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski-- true.  But so long as they pay me (with a down payment, of course) and we can work out a specific deliverable schedule, I don't care how trendy they are.

Comment: @mmr .. need a business partner?!?!?!!? I smell money .. :D

Answer (score 1):

iPad - since you can simulate the others on your mac and the iPad.

Comment: How good is the simulation?  From the arstechnica review, I can see running the other apps there, but from my understanding, it's not a perfect crossover.

Comment: The only issue I know of is image stretching when the iphone app is zoomed to fill the ipad screen. It just may not look as good. I personally don't have an ipad to test so cannot really comment on speed, OS version and hardware input issues.

Comment: I've read on Gizmodo and Engadget that you definitely should test your apps directly on the iPad before shipping it off to the App Store. Although the Simulator is good, things appear snappier on the simulator than the device sometimes. Also for iPad Dev, I recommend an external monitor, because your Simulator will look really small on your MBP.

Comment: The iPad can simulate almost all iPhone/iPod touch apps well enough for almost all purposes. The only issues I can think of would be performance (the iPad is much faster) and display pixel density (iPad's is a bit lower).

Answer (score 1):

Right now, there's way over a hundred thousand apps for the iPhone and iPod Touch, so I'd suggest developing for the iPad.  There's a lot fewer apps to distinguish yourself from.

You can use iPhone apps on an iPad, but I wouldn't recommend pushing them out without testing them on a real iPod Touch or iPhone.  The feel will be much different.  For example, I type on my iPhone one-handed while holding the phone in one hand, but the Ars Technica review of the iPad says this isn't really feasible on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get the iPad. I've been using an iPhone and now an iPad for dev work, and the iPad will run iPhone only apps at the iPhone screen size. Unless you need a camera its the best choice in being able to run apps developed for any iPhone OS device. You just should remember that app performance on an iPad will be much better then on a iPhone/iPod touch. Since it's contract work I assume its more along the lines of utilities, or basically their site as an app. So 100% performance testing isn't as crucial as a 3D game.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would always test apps on the actual target device. So, if you want to build iPad apps, you get iPad. If you want to build iPhone apps, you get iPhone or iPod Touch. iPad will run iPhone apps, but you will not be able to test for performance neither in simulator nor in iPad. Performance is always a concern on iPhone-class devices. Plus you cannot really evaluate the full iPhone user experience on iPad, because the physical form factor and screen resolution/pixel density and many other details are different.