# Which Ipod touch generation should I buy? 2nd or 3rd?

Tags: objective-c, ipod-touch

I want to create games for Iphone/Ipod touch. Unfortunately I don't have a lot of money so I can buy only one device. Ipod is cheaper than Iphone, so I decided to bought Ipod touch. But I am afraid of buying 3rd generation - because it has more memory, more faster CPU, etc. And I think if I post my app on appstore - people with 2nd generation Ipod might have trouble with my app (because I was testing it on 3rd generation). But on the other hand - I am planning to create 3d/cpu demanding game - and it would be easy for me to implement it on device with more calculation power... What should I do in this situation? Any advice is appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question a while back:

[What should I grab as a development platform, an iPod or an iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600943/what-should-i-grab-as-a-development-platform-an-ipod-or-an-ipad)

Everyone said to get an iPad.

However!  I ended up getting an iPod Touch, 3rd gen, because that's what the guy who was going to pay me said he wanted me to develop on.

All things being equal, I'd go for the lowest platform you expect your customers to use.  That way, you can be sure that even the newer people can use the app, as well as the old.

Comment: Thanks **mmr** for helping me thinking @out of the box@.
I didn't considered IPad - but maybe it's the best choice for me. 
I just have to wait another month (because of limited budget)

Answer (score 2):

2nd Generation will give you a perspective on slower performing iPhone OS devices.

3rd Generation however will support new features in the upcoming iPhone OS 4.0, most significantly the multitasking functionality.

> iPhone OS 4 will work with iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS, and the second- and third-generation iPod touch this summer, and with iPad in the fall. Not all features are compatible with all devices. For example, multitasking is available only with iPhone 3GS and the third-generation iPod touch (32GB and 64GB models from late 2009).

Source: http://www.apple.com/iphone/preview-iphone-os/

Answer (score 0):

Weird question to ask here but you should also know that the 32gb 3rd gen ipod touch has more memory and a faster CPU than the 8gb 3rd gen ipod touch.

So even within generations you still have hardware discrepancies.

Comment: IIRC, the 8gb "3rd gen" (not sure if it's called that by Apple) is actually just a 2nd generation iPod Touch.